# My video clip is playing in slow motion - I don't know why - Anyone experience this before?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am new to Blender video editing - a rookie.  I have several video clips I want to edit together ultimately making a music video. For some unknown reason, when I drag a video clip into Blender, it plays in slow motion - no idea why. Not all of the clips do it. They were all shot on the same camcorder. The ones playing in slow motion still play at the normal rate in VLC Media Player, so I know the original is fine. Has anyone else experienced this? I'm wondering if I accidentally hit something that changed the speed of this video in Blender...

Comment: Often times Blender playback is slowed down because of lack of resources in either complex scenes or in VSE with larger video files. Is it generally not reaching the fps when you want to edit this clip alone or is this clip slow at the same time together with other clips playing at normal speed?

Comment: you might wanna make sure that Blender's fps is set to the same speed as your footage (ie: if you pop a 60fps clip in, and your blender project is set to 24fps, it will play at less than half its real speed)

Comment: Thank you - I was wondering about frame rate and the example you used is exactly what's happening. Video clips I have recorded play fine in VLC media player but when I pull it into Blender, it is less than half speed. I will further explore this. Thanks again!